# i don't want go to new tab when click submit button and use url_for method post

Tags: python, html, flask

[image]

flask application #####
this is html page for login. my problem is when i ctrl+click at submit, it will have new page on new tab.
i don't want go to new tab. How can i fix this problem ?
(and use url_for method post)

i want fix this problem from phone device and computer device.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Control + Click is the way to open a link to a new tab... if even normal click will drag you to new tab, check in the code if you can see something like this

`<form target="_blank" ...`

and convert it into

`<form ...`

**EDIT**

On the comment I understand what you're looking for, so try to put this javascript in the page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("submit").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formAction = $(this).attr("action");
        window.location.href = formAction;
    });

});
```

or without jQuery

```
    document.querySelectorAll("input[type='submit']")[0].onclick = function () {
    
        var formAction = document.querySelectorAll("form")[0].action;
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = formAction;
    };
```

Please note that it will work only if there's 1 form and 1 submit (input type=submit) in the page. So no multiple forms or button submit.

Comment: no my code don't have <form target="_blank" . i ment if have the user ctrl+click at submit. thank for your answer.

Comment: thank you. <3 <3 if i want use with url_for How can i do?

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

Comment: <form action=" {{ url_for('index', data=data) }}" method="POST" id = myform>
    <input type="submit" id="mysubmit">
    <script>
document.getElementById("mysubmit").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  $("#myform").submit();
});
</script>

Comment: if you're using jQuery (script included before) 
it's enough 
$('#myform').on("submit", function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 $("#myform").submit();
 $form = $(this); 
 window.location.href =  $form.attr('action'))
});
Next time include this code in the question, and reformulate the question which wasn't clear. I think we can close this :)